# want to get all the java script file from html using bs4

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import HTMLParser
import urllib
url = raw_input('enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
scripts=soup.find_all('script')
for tag in scripts:
    try:
      Script = tag["src"]
      print Script
    except:
      print "No source"
```

using this code I m not getting all the java script from html document.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and it seems that you are getting all the javascript. At least you check for all the tags. Of course some of the javascript may be directly embedded into the html and thereby won't have a src attribute. Merely the actual javascript between the `<script>...</script>` tags. You can get the javscript between these embedded tags using `tag.contents` in your loop.

Furthermore, I would advise to specify a parser. By default bs4 uses `html.parser`. Other parsers may perform better/differently. Check out: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

r = urllib2.urlopen('<your url>').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

for s in soup.findAll('script'):
    print s.get('src')
```